Opening external data files under Fortran do loop
The command to create a new data file or to read an already created data file in Fortran is easy.
For example, open(12, file='new.dat', action='write'/'read').
But I want to do this inside a loop. Because, say I have to create 500 different data files and also read them later on. So it is very cumbersome to perform manually.
But I don't know if it can be done using this simple way at all. I think it is mainly because of the way Fortran names the files, e.g. 'new.dat' above. Inside a loop it can not, by itself, generate files continuously through assigning names to them.
I tried the following:
program test_file_opening

implicit none

!real ::
integer :: i

do i = 1, 10
 open(i, file='i.dat', action='write')
end do

do i = 1, 10
 write(i,*) 'hallo world!'
end do

end program

As expected, i is within quotation, and just one data file gets created, with only the single line text hallo world! in it.
Is there any way to create a lots of external data files (with entries specified in the code) under 'do loop' in Fortran?

@francescalus I couldn't understand that, probably need to start from more basic.

@QuestionTheAnswer It's OK to be a beginner, but indeed you should really try learning the basics of Fortran. A popular book for that is "Modern Fortran Explained". Also, there is the fortran-lang.org community and the associated forum, which is maybe more suited than SO for beginners.

This one generates 10 .dat files with "Hello world!" in them:
 program test_file_opening

    implicit none

    !real ::
    integer :: i, ios
    character(len=10) :: filename

    do i = 1, 10
        write(filename, '(I0)') i
        filename = trim(adjustl(filename)) // '.dat'

        open(i, file=filename, status='new', iostat=ios)

        if (ios /= 0) then
            print *, 'Error opening file ', filename
        else
            write(i, *) 'Hello World! ', i
            close(i)
        end if

    end do

end program

looks much longer, but write(filename, '(I0)') i converts the integer i to a string and writes it to filename, after that filename = trim(adjustl(filename)) // '.dat' appends .dat to the integer string.

Thanks! But to clear some concepts, please explain what is " '(I0)' "? Like, 'I1', 'I10', why none of those? Why no 'action="write"' statement in the 'open' command? And why 'len' is taken to be '10'?

@QuestionTheAnswer I sets the format (integer), '0' sets the minimum width. In this case, since we convert integer to string it is necessary to set the minimum size to represent the integer so that it does not get padded with spaces of zeroes.
As for opening the file without 'action="write"': default action is "readwrite", so I just omitted it. if you need to prevent reading from the file, you can put 'action="write"' back.

I mean prevent reading from within this part of code. It is still possible to read from this file from elsewhere.

I tried to utilise the same code in this answer to 'read' all the data files created.  I tried by changing "write(filename, '(I0)') i", to "read(filename, '(I0)') i". And set the "status" to "old". But on compilation, fortran is showing the error "Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)". What should I do?
